# Post a form containing a file that was created in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've constructed a CSV string in JavaScript. I then want to submit the string as though it were a file to another service on a different domain without the user having to download it and re-upload it.

I have been able to create a csv like this:

```js
function downloadCsv(csvString) {
  let csvUri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvString);
  let csvLink = document.createElement('a');
  csvLink.setAttribute('href', csvUri);
  csvLink.setAttribute('download', 'csvFile.csv');
  document.body.appendChild(csvLink);
  csvLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(csvLink);
}
```

What I'd like to do instead is attach the "file" to a form and submit it directly. I know I can create a `Blob` and attach that to `FormData`, and I can create a `<form>` much like above, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the file back into html.

Here is the vague route I've started along:

```js
function uploadCsv(csvString, url) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  let csvFile = new Blob([csvString], { type: "text/csv" });
  formData.append('csvFile', csvFile);

  let form = document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('action', url);
  form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
  form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
  let input = document.createElement('input'); // ???

  // ... magic goes here ...

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
  document.body.removeChild(form); // Probably not required due to immediate redirect
}
```

Comment: Pretty interesting problem. Not already familiar with `FormData` object, I inquired on it and got possible solution, but something is not clear to me: since you want "to submit (...) to another service on a different domain", why do you want the current page to be replaced by immediate redirect? Instead couldn't you avoid creating a DOM element from your `FormData`, and merely use an `XMLHttpRequest.send()` to transmit it?

Comment: I want the form to be submitted as if it were submitted from the browser. The next page the user should see should be on that service. Additionally, submitting in this way bypasses CORS and means I don't have to add anything new to the service I'm submitting to as that's a live product and I'm just making a prototype. :)

Comment: I don't fully understand the meaning of your last sentence. But the two first ones are clear, so I thought to an alternative workaround: transmitting your `FormData` by `XMLHttpRequest.send()` as already suggested, you might wait for success then redirect with a simple `document.location.replace(url)`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an actual page that I'm submitting to. The page I want people to see as a result will be the response to the request. Additionally, because CORS is not set up, I will not be able to send an XMLHttpRequest